# Magento 2.1 - Deploy static view files without deleting pub/static

Tags: magento2, css, static-content, less-compilation

How can I deploy static view files over the CLI in Magento 2.1 **WITHOUT** deleting my complete `pub/static/*` dir.

Our Shop runs in an auto scaling enviroment.
Everytime when we want to deploy new style changes we have to take the complete shop offline for the whole deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

Try running below commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use cache flush and deploy.**

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I am using CE 2.2.5 and doing as you said does not work for me.. Is there any steps to do to dpeloy static content without deleting the pub/static folder?